# Saving messages of MessageClass IPM.Note.EnterpriseVault.Shortcut to desktop folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to save selected messages in Outlook on a tempfolder on my Desktop.

```vb
Public Sub SaveMessageAsMsg1()
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Dim sName As String
    Dim enviro As String
      
    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
    
    For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note*" Then
            Set oMail = objItem
            sName = oMail.Subject
            ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"
            dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
            sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek,vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"
            sPath = "C:\Users\XBBLC1C\Desktop\TempEmail\"

            Debug.Print sPath & sName
    
            oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Some of the messages are already archived in Enterprise vault and while saving those messages `objItem.MessageClass` generates the value `IPM.Note.EnterpriseVault.Shortcut`.

To accommodate this I tried an asterisk with `IPM.Note` in the above code.

Comment: I've edited your post to add code formatting and indentation. But you might want to edit it further - you should specify what you mean by 'it's not working', for a start. What is the code currently doing? What should it be doing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The above code saves all outlook messages which are not archived in Enterprise vault (  If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" holds good.) as intended
But for messages which are archived  objItem.MessageClass  equals to IPM.Note.EnterpriseVault.Shortcut which I’m trying to capture in IF condition through *, but it’s not working.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but the line:

```
If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note*" Then
```

is likely not going to do the comparison you are hoping for.  While '*' is a wildcard character in certain circumstances, it isn't for a string comparison like this.

I'd suggest trying:

```
If inStr(objItem.MessageClass, "IPM.Note") <> 0 Then
```

which will be true if "IPM.Note" is anywhere in the message class

OR

```
If InStr(objItem.MessageClass, "IPM.Note") = 1 Then
```

which will be true if "IPM.Note" is at the beginning of the message class.

Similarly you could use

```
If objItem.MessageClass like "IPM.Note*" Then
```

if you want something closer to what you were originally writing.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what OpiesDad suggested and check the MessageClass property, or you can check the `MailItem.Class` property - for regular MailItem objects, it will be 43 (OlObjectClass.olMail):

```
If objItem.Class = 43 Then
  ...
```